# FIleNotFoundError when running an iteration through files in a directory using Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, file-not-found

I am attempting to iterate through csv files in a directory, extract URLs from the csv files and then save them in a list. I can successfully complete this for one file using the following code:

```
sec_urls = []
filename = './2000Q1.csv'

with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        url = line[4].strip()
        sec_urls.append(url)
        print(url, 'downloaded and added to list')
```

However when I use a for loop to try and complete this for all of the files I get an error for a specific file which I haven't named and is definitely in the list (I can rewrite the code above to single this file out). The code and corresponding error are below:

```
sec_urls = []
directory = '/Users/nicolacornforth/index'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(os.path.join(INDEX_DIR, filename), newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                url = line[4].strip()
                sec_urls.append(url)
                print(url, 'downloaded and added to list')
```

```
<ipython-input-27-f0b28aed085c> in <module>
      4 for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      5     if filename.endswith('.csv'):
----> 6         with open(os.path.join(INDEX_DIR, filename), newline='') as csvfile:
      7             reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      8             for line in reader:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './index/2007Q2.csv'
```

I'd appreciate any help please, I am an absolute beginner.

Comment: You are using `INDEX_DIR` in `os.path.join(INDEX_DIR, filename)` instead of `directory`. Or vice versa in `os.listdir(directory)`.

Comment: @fabianegli Thank You for pointing out my silly error. I've been working on this single block of code for hours! I have changed INDEX_DIR to directory and that has fixed the error.

Comment: You are welcome. Just as an additional hint: read the error messages carefully. In this case you can see that the file that was not found is lacking the absolute path that you would expect after defining `directory` as such. Error messages are your friends :-)